# Google App Engine Cache Time

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I read xml files off other servers via:

```
urllib2.urlopen(url)
```

Does Google App Engine load the url every time the page is requested or does it cache it for some time?

How long does it store the result in the cache?

Comment: where have you read it's cached?

Comment: I'm assuming Google must be caching the result of the url to avoid reading it again and again.

Comment: oh, ok. well, as far as I know that does not happen. Why not create a test script that tests this behaviour for you? Create a resource that changes every 100/th of a second then make 100 calls to that resource and compare the results.

Comment: Of course its not cached! But you can easily use memcache to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Caching is a decision made by two parties. The owner of the content sets a header on the response saying, "This content is not going to change for awhile, you can cache it." The recipient (e.g. the web browser) looks at these headers and decides whether to cache this content or not.

In your use case, the recipient is not the App Engine - it's your app. If App Engine starts caching everything, it can really wreck havoc for many apps that rely on each request being fresh. So App Engine, correctly, does nothing, leaving it to the app developer to decide what and when needs to be cached.

As Dmitry pointed out, you can use Memcache to cache anything you need in your own app.